# What's the common name of the design pattern used on the home screen of the Apple watch?

Tags: apple

I'm referring to the fish-eye/magnifier effect applied to app icons as they approach the center of the screen (animation [here](https://gifer.com/en/ABON)).

[image]

Comment: I've also heard it referred to as 'Honeycomb'

Comment: I have not seen this interaction before so it may be that it is too rare to have a common name for this. But I think magnifier is probably more apt than fish-eye.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### It's often referred to as a 'pan and zoom' pattern.

You can pan across apps, and zoom in as needed to app 'groups', to make selection easier.

As @Greg Whitham correctly mentions, the *layout* has been referred to as a 'honeycomb', but I'm just referring to the *interaction* itself.

Comment: You're right that this is a zooming interface but I think the OP is referring to the way in which the objects at the center of the screen are magnified automatically.